# chisel k Nearest Neighbors verilog output

Tags: scala, verilog, chisel

I have a problem with the generated Verilog from my chisel code below and I think this could be related to the way I have written my chisel code. Fine below the Scala version and chisel versions of my code with the generated Verilog output.

Here is the Scala version of my code:

```
class NearestNeighbours(k: Int, dataX: Array[Array[Double]], dataY: Seq[String]){                    
     object predict{                                                                                  
        def apply(X: Array[Double]): String = {                                                       
             val distances = dataX.indices.map{y=>                                                    
                val Rsum=X.zip(dataX(y)).foldLeft(0.0){case (acc, (i,j))=>                             
                 acc + ((i-j)*(i-j))                                                                    
               }                                                                                      
              sqrt(Rsum)                                                                               
             }                                                                                          
        val topKClasses = distances.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).take(k).map{case (dist, idx)=>dataY(idx)} 
             topKClasses.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1                             

      }                                                                                                  
   }                                                                                                     
}
```

Here is the chisel version. Please can someone look into my code to see where I went wrong?

```
class HardwareNearestNeighbours(val fixedType: FixedPoint,
                        val k: Int,
                        val keySize: Int,
                        val dataY: Seq[String],
                        val dataX: Array[Array[Double]]) extends Module {
   val io = IO(new Bundle {
     val x   = Input(Vec(keySize, fixedType))
     val out = Output(fixedType)
    })
      private val tabHash0 = dataX.map(_.map(_.F(fixedType.getWidth.W, fixedType.binaryPoint)))                                       
      private val distances = tabHash0.indices.map { ind1 =>
          val dist: FixedPoint = io.x.zip(tabHash0(ind1)).foldLeft(0.F(fixedType.binaryPoint)) { case (accum, (x, t)) =>
              accum + ((x-t) *(x-t))
            }
          }
      val topKClasses = distances.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).take(k).map{case (dist, idx)=>dataY(idx)}
      val label = topKClasses.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1
 io.out := label(0).toByte.toDouble.F(fixedType.getWidth.W, fixedType.binaryPoint)
}
```

This is how I run my code with values from a file:

```
object HardwareNearestNeighboursDriver extends App {

  def line2Data(line: String): (List[Double],String)=
     val elts=line.split(",")
     val y= elts.last
     val x= elts.dropRight(1).map(_.toDouble).toList
    (x,y)
  }

  val data = Source.fromFile("ionosphere.data.txt").getLines().map(x=>line2Data(x)).toList
  val outputs =data.map(_._2).toSeq
  val inputs =data.map(_._1).toArray
println("The output size is" + outputs.size)
val keySize = inputs.take(1).length
  val dataX = inputs.map(_.toArray).take(300)
  val dataY = outputs.take(300)

  val fixedWidth = 64
  val binaryPoint = 32
  val k = 5


  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new HardwareNearestNeighbours(FixedPoint(fixedWidth.W, binaryPoint.BP), k, keySize, dataY, dataX))
}
```

I have made show the data file is in the same folder. The code ran, but I am worried with the verilog generated.

```
  `ifdef RANDOMIZE_GARBAGE_ASSIGN
    `define RANDOMIZE
    `endif
    `ifdef RANDOMIZE_INVALID_ASSIGN
    `define RANDOMIZE
    `endif
    `ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
    `define RANDOMIZE
    `endif
    `ifdef RANDOMIZE_MEM_INIT
    `define RANDOMIZE
    `endif

    module HardwareNearestNeighbours(
      input         clock,
      input         reset,
      input  [63:0] io_x_0,
      output [63:0] io_out
    );
      assign io_out = 64'sh6700000000;
    endmodule
```

I would like to also have an advice on how to check the correctness of my generated verilog. I am totally new with hardware languages.
Thanks! Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: your generated verilog does not do much but initializing an output to a constant value.  I guess your code just calculated the result and generated it. What did you expect?  As for testing, you need to simulate the verilog module, provide inputs and watch outputs to make sure it works correctly. There is nothing to check in your case though.

Comment: Before you try and make the hardware work, you should write a scala test or main that demonstrates that your software implementation works.  Your computation of the keySize for instance always returns one because .take(1).length. Some description of what the data in the file means would be really helpful

Comment: Is there something specific you were hoping to achieve by declaring predict as an object with an apply function?  It looks like a rather complicated way of declaring an ordinary method named predict.

Comment: keySize is the length of 1 array in the inputs. [here is the link to data set with descriptions](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Ionosphere?ref=datanews.io). Also, I transformed inputs as an array of array.  I did the Scala main and tested that it worked first. It can be seen [here](https://github.com/Foutse/codeFoutse/blob/master/scalakNN/src/main/scala/example/NNExample.scala).

Comment: The predict was declared as an object so that I can call the function apply with predict, which I realized wasn't really necessary finally. Also, when I give the right size to keySize, the vec x is initialized, it does not take it's values from the file. I want that the vector x declared in the io Bundle should fill in itself the values of one array in my dataX. My code seem to be initializing values to x as I give to it its length(keySize) and by so doing, even if the distance was computed I will not be getting the correct results, bcause the values in x are not from my data. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is in `HardwareNearestNeighbours`:

```
  val topKClasses = distances.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).take(k).map{case (dist, idx)=>dataY(idx)}
```

The `sortBy` here is a software implementation of sort.  You need to write your own to create the necessary hardware to collect the top `k` values.  It would probably be simplest to sort into set of registers but your best strategy would depend on your design goals for the circuit.